# Replace Cell Values in Pandas with matching ID from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which contains a list of domains (or vertices/nodes in my case) which I'm storing through pandas library:

```
                 domain
0            airbnb.com
1          facebook.com
2                st.org
3              index.co
4        crunchbase.com
5               avc.com
6        techcrunch.com
7            google.com
```

I have another dataframe which contains the connections between these domains (aka edges):

```
           source_domain    destination_domain
0             airbnb.com            google.com
1           facebook.com            google.com
2                 st.org          facebook.com
3                 st.org            airbnb.com
4                 st.org        crunchbase.com
5               index.co        techcrunch.com
6         crunchbase.com        techcrunch.com
7         crunchbase.com            airbnb.com
8                avc.com        techcrunch.com
9         techcrunch.com                st.org
10        techcrunch.com            google.com
11        techcrunch.com          facebook.com
```

since this dataset will get much larger, I read that I can have faster performance if I represent the "edges" dataframe only with integers instead of strings.

So, I'm wondering if there is a fast way to replace each cell in the edges dataframe with the corresponding id from the domains (aka vertices)  dataframe?  So row 1 in the edges dataframe might end up looking like:

```
###### Before: ##################### 
1           facebook.com google.com   
###### After:  #####################   
1           1            7
```

How can I go about doing this?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try implement another answer - convert to `Catagorical` and for `ints` use [`cat.codes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.codes.html):

```
#if always unique domain in df1 can be omit
#cats = df1['domain'].unique()
cats = df1['domain']
df2['source_domain'] = df2['source_domain'].astype('category', categories=cats)
df2['destination_domain'] = df2['destination_domain'].astype('category', categories=cats)
df2['source_code'] = df2['source_domain'].cat.codes
df2['dest_code'] = df2['destination_domain'].cat.codes
print (df2)
     source_domain destination_domain  source_code  dest_code
0       airbnb.com         google.com            0          7
1     facebook.com         google.com            1          7
2           st.org       facebook.com            2          1
3           st.org         airbnb.com            2          0
4           st.org     crunchbase.com            2          4
5         index.co     techcrunch.com            3          6
6   crunchbase.com     techcrunch.com            4          6
7   crunchbase.com         airbnb.com            4          0
8          avc.com     techcrunch.com            5          6
9   techcrunch.com             st.org            6          2
10  techcrunch.com         google.com            6          7
11  techcrunch.com       facebook.com            6          1
```

---

```
df2['source_domain'] = df2['source_domain'].astype('category', categories=cats).cat.codes
df2['destination_domain'] = df2['destination_domain'].astype('category', categories=cats)
                                                     .cat.codes
print (df2)
    source_domain  destination_domain
0               0                   7
1               1                   7
2               2                   1
3               2                   0
4               2                   4
5               3                   6
6               4                   6
7               4                   0
8               5                   6
9               6                   2
10              6                   7
11              6                   1
```

If want replace by `dict` use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
d = dict(zip(df1.domain.values, df1.index.values))
df2['source_code'] = df2['source_domain'].map(d)
df2['dest_code'] = df2['destination_domain'].map(d)
print (df2)
     source_domain destination_domain  source_code  dest_code
0       airbnb.com         google.com            0          7
1     facebook.com         google.com            1          7
2           st.org       facebook.com            2          1
3           st.org         airbnb.com            2          0
4           st.org     crunchbase.com            2          4
5         index.co     techcrunch.com            3          6
6   crunchbase.com     techcrunch.com            4          6
7   crunchbase.com         airbnb.com            4          0
8          avc.com     techcrunch.com            5          6
9   techcrunch.com             st.org            6          2
10  techcrunch.com         google.com            6          7
11  techcrunch.com       facebook.com            6          1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use case for Categorial Data: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html

In short, Categorical Series will internally represent each item as a number, but display it as a string.  This is useful when you have a lot of repeated strings.

It's easier and less error-prone to use Categorical Series vs converting everything to integers manually.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is to generate a dictionary from the vertices dataframe... **IF** we can be sure that it represents the definitive set of vertices that will show up in the edges... and use it with `replace`

Since the index of the vertices dataframe already has the factor information...

```
m = dict(zip(vertices.domain, vertices.index))
edges.replace(m)

    source_domain  destination_domain
0               0                   7
1               1                   7
2               2                   1
3               2                   0
4               2                   4
5               3                   6
6               4                   6
7               4                   0
8               5                   6
9               6                   2
10              6                   7
11              6                   1
```

You can also use `stack`/`map`/`unstack`

```
m = dict(zip(vertices.domain, vertices.index))
edges.stack().map(m).unstack()

    source_domain  destination_domain
0               0                   7
1               1                   7
2               2                   1
3               2                   0
4               2                   4
5               3                   6
6               4                   6
7               4                   0
8               5                   6
9               6                   2
10              6                   7
11              6                   1
```

---

**editorial**

I wanted to comment on @JohnZwinck's answer in addition to providing information of my own.

First, `categorical` would provide faster performance.  However, I'm unclear of a way to ensure that you can have two columns of coordinated categories.  What I mean by coordinated is that each column gets a set integers assigned to each category behind the scenes.  We have know way to know or enforce (Not that I know of) that these integers are the same.  If we made it one big column, then converted that column to a categorical, that would work... However, I believe that it would turn back to object once we split up into two columns again.