# How to replace words (in one DataFrame) with matching ids from another DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Asking a variation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43960458/replace-cell-values-in-pandas-with-matching-id-from-another-dataframe) which was asked for Pandas, I have a similar situation, except I'm working with `spark-shell` or `pyspark`.

I have a dataframe which contains a list of domains (vertices):

```
index            domain
0            airbnb.com
1          facebook.com
2                st.org
3              index.co
4        crunchbase.com
5               avc.com
6        techcrunch.com
7            google.com
```

I have another dataframe which contains the connections between these domains (edges):

```
           source_domain    destination_domain
              airbnb.com            google.com
            facebook.com            google.com
                  st.org          facebook.com
                  st.org            airbnb.com
                  st.org        crunchbase.com
                index.co        techcrunch.com
          crunchbase.com        techcrunch.com
          crunchbase.com            airbnb.com
                 avc.com        techcrunch.com
          techcrunch.com                st.org
          techcrunch.com            google.com
          techcrunch.com          facebook.com
```

how can I replace each cell in the edges dataframe with the corresponding index from the domains (aka vertices)  dataframe?  So, the first row in the edges dataframe might end up looking like:

```
###### Before: ##################### 
           facebook.com google.com   
###### After:  #####################   
           1            7
```

The dataframe is going to grow to at least a few hundred gigabytes.

How can I go about doing this in Spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Save the datasets as CSV files, `vertices.csv` and `edges.csv`, respectively, `read` and `join`.

```
// load the datasets
val vertices = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("vertices.csv")
val edges = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("edges.csv")

// indexify the source_domain
val sources = edges.
  join(vertices).
  where(edges("source_domain") === vertices("domain")).
  withColumnRenamed("index", "source_index")

// indexify the destination_domain
val destinations = edges.
  join(vertices).
  where(edges("destination_domain") === vertices("domain")).
  withColumnRenamed("index", "destination_index")

val result = sources.
  join(destinations, Seq("source_domain", "destination_domain")).
  select("source_index", "destination_index")
scala> result.show
+------------+-----------------+
|source_index|destination_index|
+------------+-----------------+
|           0|                7|
|           1|                7|
|           2|                1|
|           2|                0|
|           2|                4|
|           3|                6|
|           4|                6|
|           4|                0|
|           5|                6|
|           6|                2|
|           6|                7|
|           6|                1|
+------------+-----------------+
```